# Android 11 scoped storage issue

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I'm migrating an app from android 10 to 11 and I'm having an issue with scoped storage and the Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) method.

In the current app version (targeting api level 29) and a Galaxy Xcover Pro phone (Android 10) this method returns null and I need to put  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the AndroidManifest file in order to make it work.

When I target api level 30, on my Samsung M12 with Android 11, with or without the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, the method returns this value:
*/storage/emulated/0/Pictures*, **BUT IT SHOULD'T**

Anyone has encountered this problem and could help me to solve?

**EDIT**

set correct method argument

Comment: Well what do you think it should return?

Comment: 'MyDir' is no public directory so the call is wrong.

Comment: It should return always null, or at least throw an exception, because on Android 11 calls to getExternalStoragePublicDirectory are not allowed, also if you set requestLegacyExternalStorage to true

Comment: No. That is nonsense. You can do both.